# How to replicate CouchDB conditionally?

Tags: couchdb, replication

**Following Scenario:**

I have two running CouchDBs.

*CouchDB_A* has a *database_A* which has a *version_A = 1.0* (not couchdb version! => some free defined version, a document in database_A that holds this info)

*CouchDB_B* has a *database_B* which has a *version_B = 2.0*.

There will be a replication job between database_A and database_B.

**Question:**

How can I tell my _replicator or the _replicator document to start the replication only if the condition is met (`version_A == version_B`).

In my understanding, *CouchDB_A* needs to retrieve this information from *CouchDB_B* before it runs the job, but I don't see a way how to do such thing in the replicator doc.

What I try to achieve is something like:

```
remote_version_B = getRemoteVersion()

if(local_version_A == remote_version_B) {
   start_replication_to_B
} else {
   don_t_replicate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I mean it's fairly simple to just do that in application code outside of the DB using transient replications, but regardless of the mechanism, you can't resolve the race condition between starting a replication and the version doc being updated?

The "right way" to handle this sort of thing would be to put your version inside each document. So as you write a new document you write an updated version identifier. Then your replication would use a dynamic filter to retrieve only changed documents that match its version.

So in your `_replicator` doc on the receiving DB you'd have:

```json
  continuous: true,
  filter: "the/filter",
  query_params: "your/version_doc",
```

Then you'd have `the/filter` something like:

```js
function(doc, req){
  return doc.version == req.query.version;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. I overlooked the part of the filter functions in the docs: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/json-structure.html#replication-settings

Comment: Yeah, it's indispensible.

Comment: i realize now, that the filter doesn't solve my problem. the replication of the whole DB should only start, when the value of the documents ("version_A" = "version_B") are identical. with the filter, it would check for every document (do i understand correctly?). what i try to achive is something like:
`if(version_A == version_B){start_replication} else {don_t_replicate}`
Is there a way to retrieve a doc from another DB in the replication-document (or maybe to run a script?)
I don't have an application layer at those DBs. 
Maybe my concept is not good...appreciate any help.